# Reusing a Class Throughout Codeigniter Controller

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

I am coding my first CodeIgniter application (very familiar with PHP, but not CI) and have the following setup:

I have a controller, Signup, that controls a signup process. Every function of the controller is the next step in the process. I have an object, `Did`, that I am currently loading as a library. This object's properties/variables are updated as the signup process moves along.

The issue I'm having is that the properties from one function of the Signup controller do not carry over to the next function. It is as if the class is re-constructed with every function.

Is there a way to reuse the class throughout the controller without it having to be re-instantiated? I'd rather not have to serialize and store in a session, either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look for session and serialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, there are many solutions to the same problem.  Please disregard this if it doesn't fit well with your implementation.

Keeping the signup steps in an object is a good idea- however, every time you load a new page CI rebuilds all the objects.  In order for data to persist it should be stored in the session, but that doesn't mean you have to be working with session variables in your controller.

How are you transferring data to your application?  Is it via forms or ajax?

One way you can do it is by unserializing the object from the session and storing it as an object in your controller's constructor.  That way you can still run $myObj->function() against it and use a $myObj->save() function to reserialize and store it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'd rather not work with session variables, but it looks like I may have to. I'm transferring data to the application via forms submitting to the next step in the process. Haven't thought of a "save" function within the object. That may work. Thanks.

Comment: I've used the Factory pattern within my `Did` class, with a save function utilizing the Codeigniter session class. It has worked. Thanks for the lead.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is that you are depending on the in-memory state of your application to remain from request to request.

You're expecting your class to use the same instantiation of your `Did` object between requests.

This is not how PHP/HTTP works.  Each request is handled individually and is it's own instance of your application.  So each request creates a new `Did` object.

To persist the state you need to either use Sessions to carry information between requests, use a database to handle your persistent state, or a combination of both.

[Codeigniter Sessions](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

[Codeigniter Database Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html)

Comment: Correct. I guess my question was whether CodeIgniter creates a new object, or if it allowed the instance to persist.

Comment: This is not a CodeIgniter issue, Core to PHP and the HTTP Request Model is that each request is individual, nothing ties them together outside of the session, so the answer is no PHP objects(members) do not persist between requests automatically.